# Center horizontally with both a top and bottom margin

Tags: html, css

So I've figured out how to get a top margin on a div, but I want to get a bottom margin as well and I can't figure out how to do both that and center it horizontally.

```
margin: 11em auto;
```

gives me a top margin of 11em, and centers the rest. How do I add, say, 2em margin-bottom? I tried with margin-bottom, but it wouldn't overwrite the initial margin rule, I tried putting it as something like this:

```
margin: 11em auto 0 auto 2em auto 0 auto;
```

and that didn't work.

So how would I horizontally center a div while setting both top and bottom margin values?

Comment: margin: 11em auto 2em;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the margin values in one line, is interpreted:

```
margin: 10px;
```

All margins will have 10px.

```
margin: 10px 20px;
```

Top and bottom margins will have 10px. Left and right margins will have 20px.

```
margin: 10px 20px 30px;
```

Top margin will have 10px. Left and right margins will have 20px. Bottom margin will have 30px.

```
margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
```

Top margin will have 10px. Right margin will have 20px. Bottom margin will have 30px. Left margin will have 40px.

So, you can remember:

```
margin: top right bottom left;
```

---

### Your answer:

```
margin: 11em auto 2em;
```

Comment: Why is the auto only applied on one of them?

Comment: If you type `margin: 11em auto 2em`, then the top margin will be 11em and the bottom 2em. How you omitted the `left` value, then it will have the `right` value. So, right and left margins will have the `auto` value.

Comment: Ah, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a third parameter of 2em like:

```
margin: 11em auto 2em;
```

Alternatively, you could overwrite margin-bottom with 2em:

```
margin: 11em auto;
margin-bottom: 2em;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
margin: 11em auto 2em auto;
```